# Getting custom program error: 0xbbb in Anchor?

Tags: anchor, anchor-test

I am creating a Transaction from my program and I am getting this error I don't know what this error means.

[image]

Comment: please replace the screenshot with a code block of the text to improve seo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BBB in hex to decimal would be 3003. That's an `Account did not deserialize` error according to Anchor docs. Check that you're allocating enough space(don't forget to add 8 bytes for the discriminator), and that all your data structures have the #[account] attribute.

Comment: I am creating a zero copy account so do i have to allocate space

Comment: That depends on how you're creating the account in your validator and your choice between using the zero attribute with `#[account(zero)` and using init with `#[account(init)]`. Init usually requires a space argument.